# Laravel order by children value

Tags: laravel

So I am working with laravel 8. And I have un Object `mapEvent`. This object has a oneToMany relationship  with `datas`. datas has a field `value` and a one to one to `Datatype`. and datatype has a field `ref`.

So I want all my `mapEvent` and order them by the `value` of the datas that has the dataType ref `starttime`. I tried several things but nothing seems to work.

To be more clear here is a scheme :

- MapEvent

  - datas

    - value
    - datatype

      - ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is interested in that :

```
$events = MapEvent::where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('datas', function ($query) {
                return $query->whereHas('dataType', function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('ref', 'starttime');
                })->orderBy('value');
            });
        })->get()
```